# When editor does not respond to the request for withdrawal

Tags: journals, paper-submission, editors, withdraw

I submitted a manuscript to a journal, but due to some issue with that I asked the Editor-in-Chief and Associate Editor to withdraw the manuscript from further consideration.
Despite several emails, they are not still responding me nor ended the process.

Now, what should I do? Can I submit the manuscript to another journal?

Comment: May the journal be a predatory one?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, Absolutely not such a journal and this is what makes me confused.

Comment: You do not ask for withdrawal. You inform the journal that you are withdrawing the manuscript. (Assuming this is before you have signed the copyright agreement.)

Comment: @Roland, a working strategy!

Comment: But you should of course apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Roland, For sure!

Comment: You're getting some really bad advice.  Whatever path you take should involve some sort of written acknowledgement from the first publisher that your submission is considered retracted, so as to avoid problems down the road.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Waiting forever clearly isn't practical

Comment: @user2768 Agreed! In fact, there is not any other working and timely solution.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Retraction is for published manuscripts. Withdrawal is before publication. You still own all rights to your manuscripts at this stage.

Comment: @Roland _You still own all rights to your manuscripts_ That really depends on the contents of any agreement

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> what should I do?

Send another email stating that you will consider the article retracted if you do not receive a response within one week.

> Can I submit the manuscript to another journal?

Yes, after one week.

---

Responses to comments:

> I would likely do this but I am not convinced that it precludes troubles. Imagine the same referee getting it twice. It would be confusing at least. Just to mention one case.

Referees regularly receive manuscripts twice, for instance, when a manuscript is rejected. Admittedly, this situation is different, since the reviewer may not have been notified of rejection. However, such a reviewer will likely assume that the paper has been rejected. Even if they don't, they will likely contact the editor, who will be able to promptly deal with the situation. This could even be pre-empted, for example, an unacknowledged retraction could be explained in a covering letter.

> [this] does not avoid...issues such as when the first journal and second journal both publish it...For all you know, the author may ALREADY have assigned copyright to the first journal.

From the question I assume copyright hasn't been assigned nor is the manuscript camera-ready.

Comment: I would likely do this but I am not convinced that it precludes troubles. Imagine the same referee getting it twice. It would be confusing at least. Just to mention one case.

Comment: @Alchimista Edited to respond

Comment: This seems arbitrary, and does not avoid any issues such as when the first journal and second journal both publish it.  Wishing problems away is usually a poor approach.

Comment: For all you know, the author may ALREADY have assigned copyright to the first journal.

Comment: @ScottSeidman From the OP's question I assume copyright hasn't been assigned nor is the manuscript camera-ready.

Comment: If you still hold copyright you can pretty much do as you please. It is yours. But it is probably worth sending a retraction notice by registered postal mail with a return receipt. Then you know your request/demand has been seen. (Works in US, at least.)

Comment: @Buffy, The manuscript is still in the early step and even no reviewer selected for that.

Comment: Then why wouldn't one just send an email to say "I withdraw this" and submit to another journal immediately?  What's so magic and legal about the 1 week deadline?

Comment: @ScottSeidman You have to give a reasonable amount of time. Unfortunately, _reasonable_ is undefined. Is it one day, two days, five, ...?

Answer (score 13):

Just to add to the answer from @user2768: when you submit the manuscript to another journal, mention in your cover letter what happened with the previous submission (including your one-sided correspondence with the editor).  I would write this in as neutral a tone as possible; the point is not to hurl accusations at the editor of the first journal, but to avoid any appearance of deception on your part in the eyes of the second editor.

It's impossible to say in general that this will not be an obstacle to your second submission.  As an associate editor myself, I believe it should not, but this kind of thing would definitely be looked at by the editor-in-chief.

Comment: Great point! (+1). One more question: Can such a statement cause some problem, by the way?

Comment: That is the point. Somehow you should have a receipt of your retraction statement. Clearly you will be on the right side, but you need to assure that the second editor will stand on your side. With no clear communication, the first submission might be further handled resulting, to the people unaware, as a double submission. Surely what is good in this story is that a publication from the first journal is impossible, as for there is not copyright agreement nor camera ready proof. @Eilia